# Clone entire instance of S3 bucket to another bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So I need to clone entire instance via AWS SDK for Python (boto3). But my instance have more that 5 millions objects so calling `objects_response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)` recursivly and then perform a copy on each file is taking too much time and not secure due to process fail and starting over with that amount of files. So how to make it in a fast and more secure way?

Comment: e.g. by running an [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: Use bucket replication.

Comment: S3 bucket replication only supports copying new Amazon S3 objects after it is enabled, but you can make a support request to make replication copy existing objects (see [replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html)).

Comment: When you say "clone entire instance", are you referring to an Amazon S3 Bucket? (A bucket is not called an instance, so just checking your meaning.)

Answer (score 1):

**AWS CLI s3 sync**

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`aws s3 sync` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) can copy S3 objects in parallel.

You can adjust the settings to enable more simultaneous copies via the [AWS CLI S3 Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html) file.

The `sync` command uses `CopyObject()` to copy objects, which tells S3 to copy the objects between buckets. Therefore, no data is downloaded/uploaded -- it just sends commands to S3 to manage the copy.

Running the `sync` command from an Amazon EC2 instance will reduce network latency, resulting in a faster copy (especially for many, smaller objects).

You could improve copy speed by running several copies of `aws s3 sync` (preferably from multiple computers). For example, each could be responsible for copying a separate sub-directory.

See also: [Improve transfer performance of sync command in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-improve-transfer-sync-command/)

**Amazon S3 Batch Operations**

Amazon S3 itself can also perform a Copy operation on a large number of files by using [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-basics.html):

- First, create an Amazon S3 Inventory report that lists all the objects (or supply a CSV file with object names)
- Then, create a S3 Batch Operations "Copy" job, pointing to the destination bucket

The entire process will be managed by Amazon S3.